# Patent the Code, Software or both?

Tags: software, method, methodology, language, codebase

I have not patented anything an am new to this. I have a language learning methodology by learning by an online platform. We use our own methodology developed by us and the platform was developed from the ground up by us in order to deliver the method of learning. Do I patent the code or the software itself or both.

part 2 is, there are many different mini methodologies, i.e. one for pronunciation, one for grammar etc that make up our methodology. Do I patent them individually?

Comment: Are you in the US?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't patent the code or the software, you patent the methodology. I think what you are describing is a novel algorithm applied to solving a specific problem. You can patent those (at least you used to be able to), although its a bit complicated and recent court decisions are relevant. I'm not a lawyer so I'll allow the ones who read your question to comment more. As for the actual code or software, I expect the best way to protect those is through a copyright. However as I said I'm not a lawyer.

Comment: @Richy Allum  If you find this answer acceptable, then please accept it. You get points by accepting answers.